# Change part of a ConnectionString with LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

How can I change part of a `ConnectionString` with `LINQ to XML`. For example, I only want to change the `Data Source` and `Initial Catalog` values in the following:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connStr" connectionString="Data Source=data-source;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=user;Password=pass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I understand how to change the whole connectionString attribute, but I don't want to do that, I only want to change certain parts.

I am using the following code to modify parts of a connection string and for the most part it works, but I how can I modify it so it does not remove the attribute/values that are not separated by `;`, `providerName` in this case.

```
string[] connArr = connectionString.Value.Split(';');

            for (int i = 0; i < connArr.Length; i++)
            {
                //Get the attribute and the value splitted by the "="
                string[] arrSubConn = connArr[i].Split('=');

                if (arrSubConn.Length == 2)
                {
                    string connAttr = arrSubConn[0];
                    string connVal = arrSubConn[1];

                    //Change the server name
                    if (connAttr == "Data Source")
                        connVal = environmentSettings.Server;


                    //Change the database name
                    if (connAttr == "Initial Catalog")
                        connVal = environmentSettings.Database;

                    newConnString += String.Format("{0}={1};", connAttr, connVal);
                } 
            }
```

Comment: If you need to deal with providerName do a double split, first on semicolons and then on equals. That will give you an array of arrays. You can then go in with a Where clause to only attack those arrays which contain a two-element sub array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ to XML will only be able to recover the actual connectionString attribute for you. Manipulation of the actual string element is beyond LINQ to XML's capabilities. If you want to change the string itself you are going to need to manipulate it with other functions. A quick way to do that might be to split the string on = and ;. You know that every element with an even index is a key and every odd index element is a value. You can then search for the Data Source and Initial Catalog elements and modify the values in the next array locations.

Comment: Can you elaborate on these other functions?

Comment: Need more info? (Feel free to say so if you need!)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

Comment: I understand how to change the whole attribute, but not sure if I can change a part of the attribute.

Comment: You can, but you will have to do it manually, by getting the whole attribute value using LinqToSQL then splitting it on ';' and '=', then changing it, then putting it back together.

Comment: Ah, had a feeling I might have to do that.

Comment: I posted a solution, but I have a slight problem with it.

Comment: Seeing as you have already accepted an answer, would you like to raise this as a separate question?